# Extract list keys and list of values for each row from json in python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to extract a list of keys and a list of all values for each entry from json. Consider the following json:

```
[{'height': 1.2 , 'width':2.5, 'weight':5 },{'height': 1.7 , 'width':4.5, 'weight':2 },{'height': 3.2 , 'width':4.5, 'weight':7 }]
```

And I want the output to be:

```
['height','width','weight']

[[1.2,2.5,5],[1.7,4.5,2],[3.2,4.5,7]]
```

Basically I need to load it to pandas Dataframe. I believe it will be easier to load the rows and cols directly. I can't load the `json` directly to DataFrame and I can't find an efficient way to extract rows and cols as described above.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(d)` - will do the trick

Comment: what about `df = pd.read_json(json)` ?

Comment: And if `json` is `dict` use `pd.DataFrame(d)` as mentioned `MaxU`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have mentioned, you can just pass dictionaries straight to the DataFrame constructor. However, if you really want the format you described for some reason, you can use:

```
>>> x = [{'height': 1.2 , 'width':2.5, 'weight':5 },{'height': 1.7 , 'width':4.5, 'weight':2 },{'height': 3.2 , 'width':4.5, 'weight':7 }]

>>> list(map(lambda l:list(l.keys()), x))
[['height', 'width', 'weight'], ['height', 'width', 'weight'], ['height', 'width', 'weight']]


>>> list(map(lambda l:list(l.values()), x))
[[1.2, 2.5, 5], [1.7, 4.5, 2], [3.2, 4.5, 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the json loaded in a variable, like text, you can simply do:

```
In [13]: import json, pandas

In [14]: text = json.dumps([{'height': 1.2 , 'width':2.5, 'weight':5 },{'height': 1.7 , 'width':4.5, 'weight':2 },{'height': 3.2 , 'width':4.5, 'weight':7 }])
    ...: 

In [15]: df = pandas.read_json(text)

In [16]: df
Out[16]: 
   height  weight  width
0     1.2       5    2.5
1     1.7       2    4.5
2     3.2       7    4.5

In [17]: df.columns.values
Out[17]: array([u'height', u'weight', u'width'], dtype=object)

In [18]: df.as_matrix()
Out[18]: 
array([[ 1.2,  5. ,  2.5],
       [ 1.7,  2. ,  4.5],
       [ 3.2,  7. ,  4.5]])
```